# Magento 2.3 - Customer Login custom product view

Tags: magento2.3, customer, products

We have a customer who asked that when a customer log's into their account, they can only see the products they have been allocated. Our customer is selling a type of products to different stores. And some of these have a limited product range. Instead of going through all the products on the site, they want only to see the allocated products.

Any help and ideas are appreciated.

Comment: means catalog based on customer id?

Comment: Well, the customer has several accounts for each of their employees. So We want the products for that customer group.